# Web Method and PowerShell

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, powershell, asmx, webmethod

I see a lot of information on running a Web Method from PowerShell, but is it possible to run a PowerShell command as part of a Web Method. For instance maybe run a simple `ls` command and have it return the output?

Comment: Why use a Web Method? That's part of the legacy ASMX technology. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I'm using a workflow designer in sharepoint called nintex workflow that has a web service action that can use a web method, there doesn't seem like any other actions that would let me get close to running powershell commands

Comment: I mean why not use WCF instead of an ASMX file? If you create a WCF service using `basicHttpBinding`, then it should be the equivalent of a `WebMethod`, just not obsolete.

Comment: Okay thanks john, I will look into that. This is my first time working with web services so it is all new to me.

Comment: May I ask what you read that made you think you should use a web method?

Comment: Just some example code I picked up somewhere on google happened to use it, couldn't tell you where I saw it exactly though.

Comment: Be careful of example code you see online. It may be old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily host the PowerShell engine in C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automations;

...
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
    ps.AddScript(@"Get-ChildItem c:\");
    var results = ps.Invoke();
    foreach (dynamic result in results) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Keith, If I wanted to run two individual cmdlets one after another but making sure that the second waits on the first command, how would I do this? Could I insert them both into the ps.AddScript(cmd1; cmd2)?

Comment: Yup, that would work e.g. `ps.AddScript("Get-Date;Get-ChildItem c:\windows -r;Get-Date");`.